# How to configure gcc to compile for android?

Tags: android, gcc, android-ndk

I've read in the gcc documentation that it supports building android binaries with the -mandroid and -mbionic switches. First I tried it with the native gcc built from svn. Result:

```
dancsi@dancsi-VirtualBox:~$ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/local/libexec/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.0/lto-wrapper
Target: i686-pc-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../source/configure --enable-threads --disable-nls
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.7.0 20110611 (experimental) (GCC)
dancsi@dancsi-VirtualBox:~$ g++ test.cpp -mandroid -o test.out
dancsi@dancsi-VirtualBox:~$ file test.out
test.out: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.15, not stripped
```

Basically, it failed. Next, I tried to compile the same gcc sources with target=arm-linux-androideabi, (without defining sysroot,...), and it passed the configuration, but failed to build saying pthread.h is not found:

```
In file included from ../.././gcc/gthr-default.h:1:0,
                 from ../../../combined/libgcc/../gcc/gthr.h:160,
                 from ../../../combined/libgcc/../gcc/unwind-dw2.c:37:
../../../combined/libgcc/../gcc/gthr-posix.h:41:21: fatal error: pthread.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

So, does anybody have the instructions for how to use gcc to build android binaries (I don't want to use code sourcery or android-ndk)?

EDIT:
my configure options

```
configure --target=arm-linux-android --host=i686-pc-linux-gnu --build=i686-pc-linux-gnu --disable-libssp --disable-libgomp --disable-nls --enable-languages=c,c++,java
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem as described by **dancsi** while trying to compile my own cross compilation tool chains for Android (I wanted to build a **32 bit variant** of them so I don't need to buy a 64 bit PC or do my android stuff in a VM).

I am using the tool chain sources from the official AOSP tool chain repo:

```
repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/manifest
```

The solution is to use the following 2 extra configure options: **--with-headers** and **--with-libs**.  I've got this solution by reading the following file: [android-toolchain-repo]/build/README:

> The other way is to specify the headers and libraries with --with-headers and
>   --with-libs separately.  If you configure your tree with a prefix.  The headers
>   and libraries will be copied to the install directory specified by the prefix.

For the values of those 2 extra parameters I used [android-src-repo]/prebuilts/ndk/8/platforms/android-14/arch-arm/usr/lib and [android-src-repo]/prebuilts/ndk/8/platforms/android-14/arch-arm/usr/include. [android-src-repo] is referring to my repo checkout of the base AOSP sources (in my case I am on the android-4.2.2_r1 branch of it).

The end-result of the two configure statements I need are the following:

```
./configure --target=arm-eabi --host=i686-linux-gnu --build=i686-linux-gnu --disable-gold \
    --with-gcc-version=4.6 --with-binutils-version=2.21 --with-gmp-version=4.2.4 --with-mpfr-version=2.4.1 \
    --with-gdb-version=7.3.x --with-gold-version=2.21 --prefix=/tmp/toolchain --disable-multilib \
    --with-libs=/home/boeboe/android-src/prebuilts/ndk/8/platforms/android-14/arch-arm/usr/lib \
    --with-headers=/home/boeboe/android-src/prebuilts/ndk/8/platforms/android-14/arch-arm/usr/include \
    --program-transform-name='s&^&arm-eabi-&' --with-arch=armv5te --disable-option-checking  

./configure --target=arm-linux-androideabi --host=i686-linux-gnu --build=i686-linux-gnu --enable-gold \
    --with-gcc-version=4.6 --with-binutils-version=2.21 --with-gmp-version=4.2.4 --with-mpfr-version=2.4.1 \
    --with-gdb-version=7.3.x --with-gold-version=2.21 --prefix=/tmp/toolchain \
    --with-libs=/home/boeboe/android-src/prebuilts/ndk/8/platforms/android-14/arch-arm/usr/lib \
    --with-headers=/home/boeboe/android-src/prebuilts/ndk/8/platforms/android-14/arch-arm/usr/include \
    --program-transform-name='s&^&arm-linux-androideabi-&' --disable-option-checking
```

Notice the extra **--disable-option-checking** argument which was necessary for configure to accept all arguments!

This long list of arguments was constructed by checking the original configure arguments passed for the default 64 bit version of the 4.6 gcc toolchain. This can be checked in the SOURCES files available in [android-src-repo]/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-eabi-4.6 and [android-src-repo]/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6.

In the same files, git tags can be found, so I also checkout those specific version in my [android-toolchain-repo]. For the extra modules needed by gcc, like gmp/mpfr/gdb..., I extracted the correct versions of the tar-balls available in [android-toolchain-repo]/gmp|mpfr|gdb. This was the easiest way I could find out, for my original configure statement to be able to pick up those modules.

The same technique as described above also allowed me to compile a 32 bit variant of the latest gcc 4.7 tool chain (currently being used on the MAIN branch of AOSP). The configure options were of course different in this case.

Answer (score 1):

```
    In file included from ../.././gcc/gthr-default.h:1:0,
                 from /mnt/network/source/gcc/libgcc/../gcc/gthr.h:160,
                 from /mnt/network/source/gcc/libgcc/../gcc/unwind-dw2.c:37:
/mnt/network/source/gcc/libgcc/../gcc/gthr-posix.h:41:21: fatal error: pthread.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [unwind-dw2.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-target-libgcc] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I'm getting the same error as you, but I'm  not compiling for Android. I'm trying to build w64-mingw32 compiler.

```
    AR=x86_64-w64-mingw32-ar RANLIB=x86_64-w64-mingw32-ranlib
../gcc-4.5.1/configure --prefix=/tools \
--with-local-prefix=/tools --enable-clocale=gnu \
--enable-shared --enable-threads=posix \
--enable-__cxa_atexit --enable-languages=c,c++ \
--disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-multilib \
--disable-bootstrap --disable-libgomp \
--without-ppl --without-cloog --build=$MACHTYPE --host=$MACHTYPE --target=x86_64-w64-mingw32
```

My response is so you know its not just Android, the trouble is more general then just building for the ARM architecture.
I think its a c++ issue, cause I had/have no trouble with building a c compiler alone.

Comment: I may have founds something that can help you. http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0483c/CIHDHBDG.html

Comment: Now that's good to know :) I'll try to build the linux (x64) to windows (x86_64-w64-mingw32), and will report back =...